# How long it takes till the gas reservoir is empty?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas

**We have a gas reservoir of internal pressure $p$ filled with an ideal gas of volume $V$. The gas is leaking to outer atmosphere till the internal pressure equals atmospheric pressure $p_0$. The leakage volume flow $Q$ is hold constant. How long does it take till $p = p_0$?**

As a first approximation I have used ideal gas laws this way (denoting $V_0$ the gas volume at $p_0$):

$$
V_0 = \frac{p V}{p_0}
$$

and since $V_0 = Qt$:

$$
t = \frac{p V}{p_0 Q}
$$

Is that good approximation? How could it be made more precise?

The $Q$ is not high so the inevitable decrease of $T$ is largely compensated during the process (the room is heated).

**Note:** This is similar to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137766/how-long-does-it-take-to-equalize-pressure-of-two-gas-containers) but not exactly. We have the very distinctive fact of fixed volume flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of moles in the tank at any time is $$n=\frac{pV}{RT}$$
The rate of change of the number of moles in the tank is:
$$\frac{dn}{dt}=-\frac{p}{RT}Q$$where p/RT is the molar density at time t.  If you combine these two equations, you will get an ODE for dp/dt which you can solve for p as a function of time.  The tank will stop leaking when $p = p_0$.